# Show that $\mathbb{F}^n$ has a certain basis given specific conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $C \in End(F^n)$ such that $C(ei)=e_1+...+e_n$, for $i=1,2,...,n$.

If $ n1_F \neq 0_F $, show that $F^n$ has a basis $(u_1,...,u_n)$ such that $C(u_1)=nu_1$ and $C(u_i)=0 $, for $i \neq 1$.

If $n1_F = 0_F$, show that $F_n$ has a basis $(v_1,...,v_n)$ such that $C(v_2)=v_1$ and $C(v_i)=0$, for $i \neq 2$.

I am clueless as to how to approach these sort of questions. I did a bit of searching online and nothing in lecture notes.

Could someone explain to me how exactly to approach this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think somebody asked this same exact question yesterday, except they used $T$ in stead of $C$. Anyways, note that letting $v=e_1+e_2+\dots+e_n$, we have $C(v)=nv$. This could be your $u_1$. Then try to work out what the others might be to make them come out to zero (this is just for part 1, obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n1_F \neq 0$, then let $u_1 = e_1+...+e_n$. Next, choose a basis $\{u_2,...,u_n\}$ for the kernel of the linear map from $\mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}$ given by $(a_1,...,a_n) \mapsto a_1+...+a_n$ (the kernel will have dimension $n-1$ by rank-nullity; for an explicit example, try $u_j = e_1-e_j$). It is easily checked that $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ satisfying the desired properties.

If $n1_F = 0$, then let $w_1 = e_1+...+e_n$, let $w_j = e_j -e_n$ for $2 \leq j \leq n-1$, and let $w_n = e_n$. Then $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ because the matrix whose $i^{th}$ column is $w_i$ is lower-triangiular with all diagonal entries equal to $1$ (hence has nonzero determinant). Now define $v_j := w_j$ for $j \notin\{2,n\}$, and define $v_2 := w_n$ and define $v_n:=w_2$. It is easily checked that $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ which has the desired properties.